# How to disply SummerNote Input

Tags: jquery, html, summernote

How would I do it if I wanted to create a new page displaying what is written in the SummerNote editor and when pressed Submit displays the contents of the TextEditor on a new Page, or at least, in the current page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote();
});
var newpage = document.createElement("NEWPAGE");
var markupStr = $('.summernote').eq(1).summernote('code');
```

JS Code
Html code:

```
<inout type="submit>Submit</input>
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="summernote" name="editordata"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: cant delete the post but i solved it

Comment: You can delete the post, but still it need approval.